# Including fitness electronics and gadgets

Tags: discussion

Curious if others think these should be added in scope. There are weekly questions about it, and right now we'd be happy to include a Q&A on barbell collars, but not on wearable fitness gadgets.

To me although they are a bid fad-ish it seems like it's really more of a trend and that they'll become more and more normal in the world of physical fitness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a snippet from our FAQ:

Physical Fitness Stack Exchange is for fitness professionals, athletes, trainers and enthusiasts. If you have a question about …

- improving your exercise performance or technique
- choosing a training program
- nutrition as it relates to exercise
- **gear and gadgets used during exercise**
- achieving physique milestones
- injury prevention

As you can see, the things you mention are already explicitly on-topic on our site.

Comment: Tried to add an **App** tag yesterday, was going to add a **gadget** tag today but noted my attempt to create the **app** tag has been rejected / deleted. If fitness app's and gadgets are in scope can a responsible adult please add a few tags and synonyms.